# RHEL setting a user specific max number of open files

Tags: ulimit

I've set up below values in /etc/security/limits.conf in my RHEL machine.

```
* hard nofile 65535

@student hard nofile 100000
```

Is this the correct approach when setting a user specific max number of open files?

Should the `* hard nofile` value be always greater than the sum of user specific nofile values?

Answer (score 1):

The entry starting with `*` is the default entry which applies to any user (except the users/groups with explicit limit). You can specify a limit for a specific group which can be higher or lower than the default entry limit.

There is no requirement like what you have said about the sum of user specific values.